# How to use LIKE and BETWEEN together in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like

I want to find out the list of customers whose last name should start with any alphabet between A and L?

I am using this code:

```
SELECT * FROM customers
WHERE Last_Name LIKE BETWEEN 'A%' AND 'L%';
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't.  But you have several alternatives.  Here are two:

```
where last_name >= 'A' and last_name < 'M'
where last_name regexp '^[A-L]'
```